# Template type comparison in operator == overload

Tags: c++, templates, types, queue, operator-keyword

I wrote an overload of operator == for a class that handle a queue.
In this class i use a template and the first control that i want to add is the control of the type of template.

This is the code

```
bool operator==(const Queue<T>& queue)
    {
        NodoCS<T>* NodoA = First;
        NodoCS<T>* NodoB = coda.First;

        if (this->DimQueue() != coda.DimQueue())
            return false;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DimQueue(); i++)
            {
                if (NodoA->Element() != NodoB->Element())
                    return false;

                NodoA = NodoA->NextAddress();
                NodoB = NodoB->NextAddress();
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Example:
I have this queues:

`Queue<int> queue1` and `Queue<string> queue2`

Obviously these are not equal, so how can i control that int is different from string?

I've tried to write the parameter of function in this way:

```
const Queue<T1>& queue
```

and then `if(T != T1)`....but it's wrong

Comment: Well if the template type `T` in the function argument is the same as the element type for the `Queue`, you won't even be able to compile `queue1 == queue2`.

Comment: Do you want to be able to compare `Queue<string>` to `Queue<int>` amd if so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write an overload of `operator==` which compares queues of the same type, and other for queues of different types. The latter returns `false` always:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==( const foo<T>& lhs , const foo<T>& rhs )
{
    return /* queues comparison */;
}

template<typename T , typename U>
bool operator==( const foo<T>& lhs , const foo<U>& rhs )
{
    return false;
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/W16aw2) is a running example at ideone.

Comment: Do away with SFINAE and `U` in the first one.

Comment: @Yakk thats true, I have overcomplicated that thing... Thanks :)

Comment: When you have a problem, and think 'I could solve this with SFINAE', well now you have two problems.

Comment: He is going to compare private member, do you need to add this non member function as friend in Queue template class?

Comment: @kwanti thats true, personally I always define binary operators as friends inside the class; but thats not related to the question. I have written the answer in that way because the code is more clear.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using boost or c++11,

```
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, U>, bool>::type
operator == (const Queue<U>& other)
{
    ... do member comparison here
}

template<typename U>
typename std::disable_if<std::is_same<T, U>, bool>::type
operator == (const Queue<U>& other)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok i have this errors and i haven't any ideas of how to handle them:       'Queue<std::string>::First': Unable to acces a private member declared in the class 'Queue<std::string>' (string is the second type)...'!=' binary: don't found any operator that accept a left operand of type int.

Comment: C++11 has no `disable_if`, only Boost has.

Comment: @Manu343726 you are right.  I have just realized this now. :)